# Hierarchical menu with Contentful

Tags: contentful

Contentful has a notion of "Links" which can be to many objects or one. However I can't find a way to model the reverse relationship without doubling the work (i.e. specify the children AND parent of each object).

I would like to use Contentful to power a simple navigation like so:

- Menu Item 1

  - Sub menu item 1
  - Sub menu item 2
  - Sub menu item 3
- Menu Item 2

  - Sub menu item 4
  - Sub menu item 5
  - Sub menu item 6
    -- Sub sub menu item 1

Where the links might look like `/<parent.slug>/<child.slug>/<child.slug>/`

I could find the page entry to render by traversing up the parent relationships to ensure I get a page with a slug, and a parent with a specific slug.

However, It's hard to render out child menu items without resorting to multiple API calls unless you include a "children" field in the object - which is prone to error and inconsistency.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly if I say that each item in the menu has a reference to its parent, but each parent has no knowledge of it's children?

Comment: Yes, how I'd "normally" build a tree menu structure would be just child objects having parent relationships, then be able to use an automatic reverse relationship to traverse down the tree - e.g. using the Django ORM, this is trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we had this same issue.  We have a Page model, with a refLink called 'parentPage'.  Our middleware makes 1 call to CF to get ALL pages and builds a site tree model in memory.

From this model we have methods to get children, and get URL slug.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the correct answer since it's also how we've solved it - grab all the pages into memory and go from there. It strikes me as somewhat inefficient, though I don't think there's really a better way at the moment.

Comment: Agreed, but then CF isn't designed to be a Page-centric CMS like (Wordpress, Sitecore, AEM, Umbraco, ...) It's more like Parse or Firebase, a lovely UI on top of a DB + API.

I wanted to introduce the concept of Pages to define a site as that's what authors tend to know. + Add Page, put content on page is easy.

Comment: How can u fill the value for parentPage? @WillHancock is it done manually ?

Comment: Just for the record in this old discussion, parentPage would be a field of type Reference, limited to references to items of content type Page.

Comment: Should we enable localization for `parentPage` field?

Answer (score 1):

If your items only has a child relationship you can leverage the includes concept. Simply fetch the furthest down child item and set the `includes` parameter to a high enough value (10 is max) and Contentfuls API will include all referenced content in a single API call.

You can read more about includes here: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/#/reference/links

Comment: Yes - this will allow a menu to be built, but, as far as I can tell, doesn't allow an API call to retrieve a single child object based on parent object slugs.. e.g. /grandparent/parent/child/ - If I retrieve the entire tree using a large includes value, I could do this in memory, which for a few dozen pages might be fine, but a few 1000?

Comment: If you have thousands of items in your menu it would require multiple API calls any way you put it. For a menu that large perhaps some sort of caching mechanism would be appropriate.